# integration over fibers

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$ which acts on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.

Let's consider the  action of  $H$ on $G \times V$: $$h((g,v)):= (gh,h^{-1}v), \quad h \in H , g \in G , v \in V, $$ and define the manifold $M$ to be  the quotient $G  \times_H V$. Then the projection $M = G  \times_H V \rightarrow B= G/H$ is a vector bundle.

If $\alpha $ is a differential form on $M$ and $\int_{M/B} \alpha$ denotes the integration along fibers of the $\alpha$, could you please explain to me how can we integrate $\alpha$ along fibers ?

Comment: Is $\int_{M/B} \alpha$ a Constant function ?

Comment: I have asked the question in the link and it's different from this one,  I don't understand why did you close the question !